# Access properties file key

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I have properties file in serverpath.properties, and a xml file named search-servlet.xml
there location is like  /properties/serverpath.properties and /src/spring/search-servlet.xml

serverpath.properties contains the following key value pair
**wmcorelib.authentication.url = http://qae.ws.wiley.com:8001/als**

now I want to use this key **wmcorelib.authentication.url** inside my xml.

Any help will be great

Comment: Do you want to use it at runtime or compile time?

Comment: I want it Compile time

Comment: You can load properties into hashmap, parse XML and then iterate its nodes. If you find match with your map, replace key with value. Is this postprocessing suitable for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am unable to understand the solution.
I just need to access that key in my xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is search-servlet a bean definition file? if so you can use spring place-holder tag that will read the properies file and replace keys from search-servlet with their values from the properties file. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: yes it is a bean definition file. I have used 'place-holder' tag.
But it is rendering like  /classpath:/properties/myfile.properties.
That extra '/' before classpath is creating error